# Is it a mistake to say 'Greg is taller than me in our class'?

Tags: comparative-constructions

I know it's not common to say like that , but is it a mistake.
Let's say we've got a question "Who is taller than you in your class?", is it ok to answer "Greg is taller than me IN MY CLASS"
or should it be just "Greg is taller than me"?
Thanks

Comment: I corrected the question and changed the examples a bit. Can you clarify,please.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why you're unsure whether it's correct? My guess before was the preposition, but that wasn't right. If we can't tell what aspect of English you're actually asking about, this question might get closed for asking for proof-reading, which is off-topic for this site. I'm trying to help you keep this question open and get some good answers.

Comment: Ok, I got it. If you see no problems with the sentence I guess it's alright. Thank you sir

Comment: There is no reason to repeat _in my class_. The question means "Who, among the people in your class, is taller than you?" Since you name Greg, it's obvious that he must be one of those people.

Comment: I agree with Kate.  Saying "Greg is taller than me *in our class*" makes it sound like maybe he's shorter than you when you're not in class!

Comment: yes, that's what I was talking about. Sounds a bit weird, so is it a mistake or just uncommon?

Comment: Not a _mistake_, just an unnatural way to say it. To answer that question, just say "Greg is taller than me" (or, more correctly, "than I am").